# Playing custom audio formats with audio stream

Tags: java, audio, format

So I started working on a video game and I want to create a custom sound format.

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:", "Users", "Mariobro85", "Desktop", "test.wav");

public void playFile() throws InterruptedException{
    try{
        File f = new File(file.toString());
        URL url = f.toURI().toURL();

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);

        clip.start();

        Thread.sleep(15000);
    }
    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uafE){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Audio data of the file " + file + " is not in wave format.");
    }
    catch(IOException ioE){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Audio data of the file " + file + " is corrupted.");
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException luE){
        System.out.println(luE);
    }
}
```

But this only plays standard .wav files.
I use wav in the custom format too, but the problem is that the audio data in my file starts at 0x60 instead of 0x0 and also there is information stored for loops, volume etc. Because of that it always throws an UnsupportedAudioFileException.

Is there any way to tell the AudioStream to jump to a specific address or is that not possible with standard java libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit the audio data before it is parsed by the default audio parser, you can edit it as follows

```
  File file=new File("path/to/file");
    byte[] bytes= Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    //edit or trim bytes as you wish.
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);//you can even give an offset in this constructor
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputStream);

    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);

    clip.start();
    Thread.sleep(xAmount);
```

If your format is truly custom, I recommend just following one of these standardised approaches and simply adding a header or footer to your byte array. No need to remake what has been done. Or, to make things simpler, you can just add a separate file you also load which has different data you wish to load with the audio.